# Shadow title-like box in beamer

Tags: beamer, boxes

I'd like to have the same box as the title one. I try an imitation, but is there a direct way with `beamer` stuff ?

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\RequirePackage{fourier}    % mettre serif dans les options Beamer

% Enlève les icônes de navigation
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\RequirePackage{tikz}       % Tikz and Co
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}    % pas de babel sinon problème
\setdefaultlanguage{french}     % avec : et !

\usetheme{Warsaw}               % thème
\usecolortheme{wolverine}       % variante de couleur

\setbeamersize{text margin left=.4cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=.4cm}

\newcommand{\Sablier}{\fontspec{Symbola}^^^^231b}

\title{\textbf{\textsc{La Boîte à Questions}}}
\author{Mathématiques}
\date{6$^{e}$}
\institute{2014 -- 2015}

\newcounter{Q}
\setcounter{Q}{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

    \stepcounter{Q}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \transduration{2}
        \frametitle{%
            \textbf{Question \theQ}}
        \centering\Huge
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle}
        \tikz\node[fill=bg,text=fg,rounded corners=5pt,blur shadow] {\Sablier{} : 3 sec.} ;
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `beamer` itself uses `beamercolorboxes`, so you could also use theme to get a good imitation

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}               % thème
\usecolortheme{wolverine}       % variante de couleur

\setbeamerfont*{title}{series=\bfseries}

\title{La Bote Questions}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true,ht=0.3cm,dp=0.3cm,center]{title}
                \usebeamerfont{title} \usebeamercolor*[fg]{title}           test
            \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]